# Spring MVC VersionResourceResolver / ContentVersionStrategy not working correctly in JSP

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC (4.3.0) application and have registered a VersionResourceResolver with added ContentVersionStrategy with the ResourceHandlerRegistry. I have the ResourceUrlEncodingFilter enabled.

```
    @Bean
    public ResourceUrlEncodingFilter resourceUrlEncodingFilter() {
        return new ResourceUrlEncodingFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        boolean devMode = this.env.acceptsProfiles("local");
        //boolean useResourceCache = !devMode;
        Integer cachePeriod = devMode ? 0 : (60 * 60 * 24 * 365); //If dev clear cache else 1 year

        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/")
                .setCachePeriod(cachePeriod)
                .resourceChain(false)
                .addResolver(new VersionResourceResolver()
                    .addContentVersionStrategy("/**"))
                .addTransformer(new AppCacheManifestTransformer());
}
```

When I access anything in /resources (JS, Images, CSS, etc) on a JSP page using the c:url or spring:url tags, the "versioned" URL does not show up (meaning: no hash code in the URL). Example:

```
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/views/login.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
```

Produces: /myapp/resources/css/views/login.css as the URL string when inspecting the page.

But, if I use a ResourceURLProvider in my Controller, I ***do*** see the hash code in the URL:

```
@Autowired
private ResourceUrlProvider mvcResourceUrlProvider;

@RequestMapping(value = { "/" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String projectBaseRedirect() {

    logger.debug("js =  '" + this.mvcResourceUrlProvider.getForLookupPath("/resources/js/views/overview.js") + "'");
    logger.debug("css =  '" + this.mvcResourceUrlProvider.getForLookupPath("/resources/css/views/overview-page.css") + "'");

    return "redirect:/admin/overview";
}
```

The log messages produce this:

```
2016-07-09 11:47:19   DEBUG AdminLoginController:35 - js =  '/resources/js/views/overview-36d1ff98d627d92a72d579eca49dbd8a.js'
2016-07-09 11:47:19   DEBUG AdminLoginController:36 - css =  '/resources/css/views/overview-page-d47f10e5bcf0fdd67bd8057479b523f0.css'
```

Why is this working in the controller but not on my JSP pages?

I am also using Spring Security (4.1.0)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it is missing in your example it is maybe missing in your project as well. You need a resource provider for the template engine you're using. In case of JSP, register a filter:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Bean
  public ResourceUrlEncodingFilter resourceUrlEncodingFilter() {
    return new ResourceUrlEncodingFilter();
  }
}
```

Or use a filter registration bean with that filter:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Bean
  public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {
    final FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new ResourceUrlEncodingFilter());
    filterRegistrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    return filterRegistrationBean;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I do have the ResourceUrlEncodingFilter in my setup. I'll update my original post to include it. I tried commenting that out and adding your second code block, but it looks like it's only available in Spring Boot (which I'm not using for this application).

Comment: Michael's suggestion is still right. If not using Spring Boot just register the ResourceUrlEncodingFilter in the usual ways (web.xml, WebApplicationContextInitializer, etc) and make sure it's mapped for the URLs serving static resources.

Comment: That was *exactly* it!! You guys rock! I put this code in my class that extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer and now it works! '@Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic fr = servletContext.addFilter("resourceUrlEncodingFilter",
                new ResourceUrlEncodingFilter());
        fr.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
        fr.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
        fr.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*"); }'

Answer (score 4):

Rossen's comment on Michael's answer was exactly the missing glue I needed. After I put this code in the class that extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer, it worked perfectly with the other code from my original post!

```
@Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic fr = servletContext.addFilter("resourceUrlEncodingFilter",
                new ResourceUrlEncodingFilter());
        fr.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
        fr.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
        fr.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I had traced it down to seeing where the encoding was being skipped. Just wondering where you found the info about the "forceEncoding" parameter? I have looked everywhere and was unable to find the info.