# VersionResourceResolver not working

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, version-control

I have static resources' structure like this in my spring application :

```
\src
    \main
        \webapp
           \resouces
              \css\..
              \js\..
```

and have configured VersionResourceResolver like this :

```
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/")
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(365, TimeUnit.DAYS)).resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new VersionResourceResolver().addContentVersionStrategy("/**"));
    }
```

I included the resources using jstl in my jsp:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/js/my.js"/>"></script>
```

But when i run the application I cannot see any kind of versioning.
What am I missing ?

Also I have tried :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38407644/3603806

But no luck

**UPDATE**

I am including resources like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/mycss.css?v=2" />">
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/js/myjs.js?v=1"/>"></script>
```

and this is what is getting generated :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/resources/css/mycss.css?v=2">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/resources/js/myjs.js?v=1"></script>
```

index page using :

```
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

Controller : for home etc...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView home(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model) {
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might be ***`ResourceUrlProvider is null`*** for you in `encodeURL` of `ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.ResourceUrlEncodingResponseWrapper`

```
@Override
        public String encodeURL(String url) {
            ResourceUrlProvider resourceUrlProvider = getResourceUrlProvider();
            if (resourceUrlProvider == null) {
                logger.debug("Request attribute exposing ResourceUrlProvider not found");
                return super.encodeURL(url);
            }
            initIndexLookupPath(resourceUrlProvider);
            if (url.length() >= this.indexLookupPath) {
                String prefix = url.substring(0, this.indexLookupPath);
                int suffixIndex = getQueryParamsIndex(url);
                String suffix = url.substring(suffixIndex);
                String lookupPath = url.substring(this.indexLookupPath, suffixIndex);
                lookupPath = resourceUrlProvider.getForLookupPath(lookupPath);
                if (lookupPath != null) {
                    return super.encodeURL(prefix + lookupPath + suffix);
                }
            }
            return super.encodeURL(url);
        }
```

To fix it, register `ResourceUrlEncodingFilter` in `web.xml` or in `WebApplicationInitializer`, as follows:

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>resourceUrlEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>resourceUrlEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
```

where `spring-dispatcher` is `DispatcherServlet`, as:

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

And make sure your `my jsp` is rendered through `spring-dispatcher`, for example:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/my-jsp", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home() {
        return "my";
    }
}
```

I created a sample app available on GitHub - [spring-resource-versioning](https://github.com/arpitaggarwal/spring-resource-versioning), which can answer your further questions.

Hope it help!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will give it a try

Comment: No. This also not working for me. My js and css files are getting loaded without any versioning :(

Comment: Can you show us your `jsp` page as well as how you are getting it rendered on the browser?

Comment: Can you the controller who is responsible for loading the page having all these `js` and `css` url's defined?

Comment: Are you trying to get the versioned files in `index.jsp`, if yes it will not as I already mentioned in my answer `And make sure your my jsp is rendered through spring-dispatcher`.

Comment: Dude you rock _/\\_

Comment: Having this exact issue on latest version of spring and none of the suggested solutions have worked :-(

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same issue like 1 hour ago. I solved it by overriding this method:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

VersionResourceResolver versionResolver = new VersionResourceResolver()
        .addFixedVersionStrategy(version, "/**/*.js")
        .addContentVersionStrategy(version, "/**/*.css", "/**/*.png"); //adjust those paths according to the webapp's folder names

registry.addResourceHandler("/res/**")
        .addResourceLocations("/resources/")
        .setCachePeriod(CACHE_SECONDS)
        .resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(versionResolver);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This does not help me. I want to enable versioning of the static resources. And i am still not getting it.

Comment: I am very well able to reach my js and css files.

Comment: @HimanshuTyagi new VersionResourceResolver() .addFixedVersionStrategy(version, "/**/*.js")
            .addContentVersionStrategy(version, "/**/*.css", "/**/*.png");

Comment: @HimanshuTyagi dude look here you might find some code that maybe helpful to you: http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.VersionResourceResolver

Answer (score 0):

As Arpit Aggarwal said, you need `ResourceUrlEncodingFilter` that corresponds to your main `DispacherServlet`. But adding it in java config didn't help me.

I solved this issue by replacing

```
@Bean
public ResourceUrlEncodingFilter resourceUrlEncodingFilter() {
    return new ResourceUrlEncodingFilter();
}
```

with

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<?> resourceUrlEncodingFilterRegistration() {
    FilterRegistrationBean<ResourceUrlEncodingFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
    registration.setFilter(new ResourceUrlEncodingFilter());
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    return registration;
}
```